Issue: oracle linux UI goes black
I'm using the oracle linux verison
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.15.0-207.156.6.el9uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Thu Jun 6 02:32:40 PDT 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I'm facing the issue, whenever I try to login to the OS before asking password the screen flickers and goes black.
What we have tried:

Restarted the system
Changed the display cables
Changed the screens

Note: the Linux is working fine for CLI
Is there any solution for this?

what is the hardware, especially video hardware? Are you talking about GUI (X or Wayland) or shell console?
